# facebook mobile ad display an error that "An unknown error occurred"

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I want to use facebook's mobile ad.

When I create facebook's APP INSTALL AD, I got the error which says "An unknown error occurred".

I used power editor.
My new android app which I want to advertise has been in google play for 2days. When I changed app which created two months ago, and create ad ,then it works.

What should I do for this error.

Java source code is as follows,

```
@ Override
public void onResume () {
super.onResume ();
com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp (this, "APP_ID");
}
```

Comment: Please look into the logs for the actual Exception. In eclipse, use the logcat tab. With adb, use adb logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the correct settings are in the developer app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps - you may need to make sure you have entered your package name correctly.

Not having measurement configured does not stop you from running an ad.